# Login to Facebook comments using embedded UIWebView through Facebook SSO

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, uiwebview, single-sign-on

Is there any method to login facebook comments embbedded in UIWebView using SSO?

In my case ,I am developing website and native ios app.

so I should embbed page like below link in my native app.

http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/19/facebook-contact-sync/

this page is using facebook comments.

If I ask users one more login, this problem can be solved.

But I want to login through facebook SSO.(Don't want to ask one more user's id and password)

[Facebook-ios-sdk with embedded UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535479/facebook-ios-sdk-with-embedded-uiwebview)

this link showing me how to login my comments box in UIWebView using ios SDK...

is Answer at this link possible?

Get Access token using iOS facebook SDK,

and passing this token to java script at page to authentication user at comments box.

If it is possible, How to pass access token that acquired from ios SDK to java script SDK ?

or Does there exist another method?

I think easiest way to implement this is make session cookies for webview using access token.

but people saying this is impossible.

[Loading iPhone webviews as an Facebook SSO authenticated user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736869/loading-iphone-webviews-as-an-facebook-sso-authenticated-user)

is it still impossible at new version of SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a decent solution. One I have it to give away SSO

Comment: I still finding solution. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535479/facebook-ios-sdk-with-embedded-uiwebview
this answer is looks like closest solution.

Comment: refer to this one also. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12627260/751026

Comment: You must Get info from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870492/facebook-ios-sdk-login-native-and-uiwebview-login/22167103#22167103